# How to pretty-print an NSError object in Xcode console?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, macos, debugging

I printed an NSError object in the Xcode console (via `NSLog(@"%@", error);`) and for a certain kind of error, this is what I get:

```
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133020 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133020.)" UserInfo=0xe939170 {conflictList=(
    "NSMergeConflict (0xe93cad0) for NSManagedObject (0x5dba970) with objectID '0x5dc26f0 <x-coredata://775D53AE-58A4-4B18-BA52-D46781A183AE/SomeObject/p1>' with oldVersion = 2 and newVersion = 3 and old object snapshot = {\n    creationDate = \"2011-08-24 06:52:22 +0000\";\n    prop1 = \"a65e349a-b315-488e-b7f8-e459e353fd6e\";\n    username = \"test-user\";\n    password = \"foobar\";\n} and new cached row = {\n    creationDate = \"2011-08-24 06:52:22 +0000\";\n    prop1 = \"a65e349a-b315-488e-b7f8-e459e353fd6e\";\n    username = \"test-user\";\n    password = \"foobar\";\n}"
```

When I replace all the '\n's with newline and all the \"s with " in emacs, I get a much nicely formatted error message:

```
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133020 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133020.)" UserInfo=0xe939170 {conflictList=(
    "NSMergeConflict (0xe93cad0) for NSManagedObject (0x5dba970) with objectID '0x5dc26f0 <x-coredata://775D53AE-58A4-4B18-BA52-D46781A183AE/SomeObject/p1>' with oldVersion = 2 and newVersion = 3 and old object snapshot = {
    creationDate = "2011-08-24 06:52:22 +0000";
    prop1 = "a65e349a-b315-488e-b7f8-e459e353fd6e";
    username = "test-user";
    password = "foobar";
} and new cached row = {
    creationDate = "2011-08-24 06:52:22 +0000";
    prop1 = "a65e349a-b315-488e-b7f8-e459e353fd6e";
    username = "test-user";
    password = "foobar";
}"
```

I would much prefer to see this nicely formatted error message in Xcode itself rather than copy-paste it and search-and-replace characters in another editor. Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT** For clarity, the error is generated by a core data save operation:

```
NSError *error
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

The offending part of the error object in this case (from where the \n's and \"s are being printed) is the value of the `conflictList` key in the error's `userInfo` dictionary.

Comment: Have you tried simply `NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);` or `po [error userInfo]`?

Comment: Yeah I tried printing error's `userInfo`. Got the same output as the previous one except that the error domain and code are not printed.

Comment: What does `po [error userInfo]` mean?

Comment: The error simply contains a lot of information. I'm sure the documentation tells you what the `userInfo` object contains so you'd be able to print out the parts that you want to see. If you post a bit more code so we can see where the error object is coming from, I can look at the documentation to see...

Comment: `po [error userInfo]` is a command for the debugger to print out the userInfo dictionary, similar to the `NSLog` statement.

Comment: The error is generated by a core data save operation. The offending bit here is the `conflictList` key of the error's `userInfo` dictionary (have also added this info to the main question).

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the debugger's `po` command. Now, when I print `po [error userInfo]`, I get the same output as above. But, when I print `po [[error userInfo] valueForKey:@"conflictList"]`, I _do_ get a nicely formatted output. If it helps, the value of the `conflictList` key is an NSArray.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a good general solution to this. Errors have varying userInfo dictionaries.

Answer (score 9):

userInfo is a NSDictionary

```
 NSLog(@" error => %@ ", [errorOrNil userInfo] )
```

Prints something like this for me

```
error => {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "User already exists";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "";
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "Retry request based on information in `NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey`";
    kinveyErrorCode = UserAlreadyExists;
    kinveyInternalErrorString = "";
    kinveyRequestId = e5be0aed155e4925b3365d57de3dc5b2;
}
```

You can also try:

```
 NSLog(@" error => %@ ", [errorOrNil localizedDescription] )
```

Which prints out:

```
You got an error: User already exists
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a very cool solution - you can write your own category for the NSError class and represent the text as you want.

Comment: Interesting solution -- but I am looking for a more general once since I don't know what kind of errors I will get in the future. e.g. In this case, the @"conflictList" key of the error's `userInfo` dictionary is the culprit. This will not always be the case.